# Как избежать ошибки при встраивании стилей в svg спрайт

Tags: html, css3, svg, svg-спрайт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В спрайте ниже встроен тэг `<style>`, с ним проект не грузится(скрин ошибки прикрепил). Если удаляю тэг стилей всё работает

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 145 40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <style>
    :root > svg {
      display: none;
    }

    :root > svg:target {
      display: block;
      --color-main: var(--fill);
      }
  </style>

  <svg id="desktop" viewBox="0 0 145 40" style="--sparks: visible; --glasses-full: hidden; --common-fill: var(--fill);">
    <use href="#full"/>
  </svg>
  <svg id="tablet" viewBox="0 0 145 40" style="--sparks: hidden; --common-fill: var(--fill);">
    <use href="#full"/>
  </svg>
  <svg id="mobile" viewBox="71 17 74 23" style="--common-fill: var(--fill);">
    <use href="#pink"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="light-desktop" viewBox="0 0 145 40" style="--sparks: visible; --glasses-full: hidden; --color-sparks: #d22856; --common-fill: var(--fill, #fff);">
    <use href="#full"/>
  </svg>
  <svg id="light-tablet" viewBox="0 0 145 40" style="--sparks: hidden; --common-fill: var(--fill, #fff);">
    <use href="#full"/>
  </svg>
  <svg id="light-mobile" viewBox="71 17 74 23" style="--common-fill: var(--fill, #fff);">
    <use href="#pink"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="logo" viewBox="71 17 74 23">
    <use href="#pink"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="full"  viewBox="0 0 145 40">
    <path id="glasses" d="m53.892 6.586 5.038 21.145c.299.915-.429 1.904-1.403 1.832H53.52c-.69 5.812-5.57 10.315-11.489 10.315-5.917 0-10.798-4.503-11.488-10.314h-1.965C27.887 35.442 22.953 40 16.968 40c-5.994 0-10.934-4.573-11.612-10.466H1.45C.501 29.58-.205 28.63.057 27.73L5.105 6.586C5.455 4.26 7.639 0 13.486 0c2.014 0 2.014 2.971 0 2.971-4.707 0-5.438 3.694-5.496 4.1L3.34 26.602h2.035c.746-5.817 5.652-10.31 11.593-10.31 5.939 0 10.843 4.488 11.593 10.3l1.998.01c.745-5.75 5.598-10.189 11.473-10.189 5.886 0 10.746 4.456 11.477 10.222v-.053h2.137l-4.639-19.51c-.068-.407-.77-4.1-5.497-4.1-2.01 0-1.89-2.972 0-2.972 5.848 0 8.03 4.259 8.382 6.586zm-28.11 21.56c0-4.935-3.946-8.936-8.814-8.936-4.867 0-8.813 4-8.813 8.936 0 4.935 3.946 8.936 8.813 8.936 4.868 0 8.814-4 8.814-8.936zm24.944 0c0-4.868-3.893-8.815-8.694-8.815-4.802 0-8.695 3.947-8.695 8.815 0 4.868 3.893 8.815 8.694 8.815 4.802 0 8.695-3.947 8.695-8.815z" fill="var(--common-fill, #d22856)" style="visibility: var(--glasses-full, visible);"/>
    <path id="glasses-clipped" d="M58.93 27.731 53.892 6.586C53.54 4.26 51.358 0 45.51 0c-1.89 0-2.01 2.971 0 2.971 4.727 0 5.429 3.694 5.497 4.1l4.639 19.511h-2.137v.053a11.75 11.75 0 0 0-5.194-8.343A2.482 2.482 0 0 0 47 20.5c0 .132-.013.26-.037.385a8.84 8.84 0 0 1 3.763 7.26c0 4.87-3.893 8.816-8.694 8.816-4.802 0-8.695-3.947-8.695-8.815 0-1.302.279-2.537.778-3.65A1.998 1.998 0 0 1 32 22.5a.526.526 0 0 0-.03-.154 11.765 11.765 0 0 0-1.411 4.256l-1.998-.01c-.75-5.812-5.654-10.3-11.593-10.3-5.94 0-10.847 4.493-11.593 10.31H3.34L7.99 7.072c.058-.407.789-4.1 5.496-4.1C15.5 2.971 15.5 0 13.486 0 7.64 0 5.456 4.259 5.105 6.586L.057 27.731c-.262.9.444 1.849 1.393 1.803h3.906c.063.549.163 1.086.297 1.61.278-.28.347-.545.347-.644a2 2 0 0 1 2.162-1.994 9.22 9.22 0 0 1-.008-.36c0-4.935 3.947-8.936 8.814-8.936 4.868 0 8.814 4 8.814 8.936 0 4.935-3.946 8.936-8.814 8.936a8.695 8.695 0 0 1-5.212-1.73A1.994 1.994 0 0 1 11 35.5c-.1 0-.367.07-.648.352-.282.282-.352.549-.352.648 0 .352-.091.683-.251.97a11.542 11.542 0 0 0 7.22 2.53c5.984 0 10.918-4.558 11.609-10.436h1.965c.69 5.81 5.57 10.314 11.489 10.314 5.917 0 10.798-4.503 11.488-10.314h4.007c.974.071 1.702-.918 1.403-1.833zM37.15 17.505c.503-.237 1.025-.44 1.565-.603A2 2 0 0 0 40.495 18h.013c.98.003 1.814.55 2.223 1.36a8.572 8.572 0 0 0-3.77.537 2 2 0 0 0-1.811-2.391z" fill="var(--common-fill, #d22856)"/>
    <g id="sparks" style="visibility: var(--sparks);">
      <path d="M49.5 16C47 16 45 14 45 11.5c0 2.5-2 4.506-4.5 4.5 2.5 0 4.5 2 4.5 4.5 0-2.5 2-4.5 4.5-4.5zM37 19.5c-1.5 0-3-1.5-3-3 0 1.5-1.5 3-3 3 1.5 0 3 1.5 3 3 0-1.5 1.5-3 3-3zm-26 14c-1.5 0-3-1.5-3-3 0 1.5-1.5 3-3 3 1.5 0 3 1.5 3 3 0-1.5 1.5-3 3-3z" fill="var(--color-sparks, #283645)"/> <path id="spark" d="M97.5 9.5A3.485 3.485 0 0 1 94 6a3.483 3.483 0 0 1-3.5 3.5c1.944 0 3.5 1.556 3.5 3.5 0-1.944 1.556-3.5 3.5-3.5z" fill="#d22856"/>
    </g>
    <path id="pink" d="M71.005 18.286c0-.687.563-1.27 1.252-1.286h7.133c5.057 0 8.385 2.702 8.385 7.13 0 4.893-4.331 7.68-8.802 7.68h-5.435v6.8c0 .907-.681 1.397-1.32 1.39-.628-.006-1.213-.496-1.213-1.39V18.287zm8.067 11.231c3.06 0 6.14-1.918 6.14-5.308 0-3.21-2.395-4.876-5.961-4.876h-5.663v10.144l5.484.04zm13.522-11.128c-.158-1.78 2.69-1.78 2.533 0v20.222c0 1.8-2.533 1.8-2.533 0V18.389zm9.08.133c0-1.74 1.826-2.022 2.881-.509l13.601 17.4V18.462c0-1.75 2.464-1.75 2.464 0v20.292c.053 1.502-1.955 1.394-2.593.398l-13.909-17.808v17.41c0 1.551-2.412 1.634-2.399.078l-.045-20.31zm25.264-.133c0-1.8 2.534-1.8 2.534 0v12.295l12.756-13.133c1.272-1.271 3.055.449 1.798 1.706l-7.948 7.897 8.532 10.496c1.207 1.403-.61 3.35-1.945 1.669l-8.365-10.46-4.828 4.846v4.886c0 1.63-2.524 1.63-2.524 0l-.01-20.202z" fill="var(--common-fill, #283645)"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вы его встраиваете? Пропишите ему класс и выносите стили наружу

Comment: Да, вы правы. В итоге я так и сделал. Просто этот кусок кода не мой, я пытался разобраться как это работает(и запускается без ошибок). . и это осталось для меня загадкой